# Make apachectl restart more verbose on Mac 10.8

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm using the standard Apache server in my Mac OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion) installation, and find that when running

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

The command simply shows the prompt when finished, whether Apache failed to start or not. There is no feedback, until you refresh your browser to see if localhost still works or not.

Is there a way to configure Apache to be a bit more verbose?

Answer (score 14):

You could try:

```
sudo apachectl -e info -k restart
```

The `-e` option is equivalent to the [`LogLevel` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#loglevel), but it logs to your terminal. Replace `info` with `debug` for more details.

The `apachectl` script and the `httpd` binary have slightly conflicting arguments, so you need to use `-k` with `stop`, `start`, `restart` and `graceful` (the command keywords alone will not work as expected when other arguments are present). To get `configcheck` use

```
sudo apachectl -e info -t
```

This applies to Apache on any platform using the standard `apachectl` script.

This [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/150249/best-way-to-troubleshoot-apache-not-starting) has another option, but I consider `strace` (and `dtrace`, `ktrace`, `truss`) to be more of a last resort...

Answer (score 0):

I just tend to `echo $?` to get the exit status. Or do a quick `ps aux | grep apache` or `ps aux | grep httpd` (depending on the OS) to check for the service after restarting.